# glove = pickle.load(f) EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pickle

So here:

```
glove_path = './embeddings/glove_{}_{}.pkl'.format(dataset,mode)
if(os.path.isfile(glove_path)):
        print("Reusing glove dictionary to save time")
        #with open(glove_path,'r') as f:
        with open(glove_path, 'rb') as f: #python 3 for pickle byte size object is needed not str
                glove = pickle.load(f)
        save = False
```

If I try

```
with open(glove_path,'r') as f:
```

I get the following error:

```
Reusing glove dictionary to save time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prepare.py", line 315, in <module>
    glove = pickle.load(f)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and if I try

```
with open(glove_path, 'rb') as f: #python 3 for pickle byte size object is needed not str
```

I get the following error:

```
Reusing glove dictionary to save time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prepare.py", line 315, in <module>
    glove = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Can you please guide how to fix this?

I am using the code from https://github.com/vanzytay/pytorch_sentiment_rnn and using `Anaconda Python 3.6`.

I have imported pickle like

```
import six; from six.moves import cPickle as pickle #import compatability with Python 2 using six
```

while it was originally imported as:

```
import cPickle as pickle #python 2
```

Answer (score 3):

"EOFError: Ran out of input" means that you are trying to read empty file.
Check if file that you are trying to read from is not empty.

Comment: the file was not empty but my guess it was malformed. when I do the same task with Anaconda Python 2 I get no error.